# Solve $\max_{\lambda} \mathrm{sum} (\lambda \vec{u} \geq_c \vec{v})$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Let $\vec{u},\vec{v} \in R^n$ be known vectors. I want to find out the optimum scalar multiplier $\lambda$, to maximize the number of elements in $\lambda \vec{u}$ which are above $\vec{v}$.

In other words,
\begin{align}
& \underset{\lambda \in R}{\mathrm{argmax}}\, \mathrm{sum}(\lambda \vec{u} \geq_c \vec{v}) \\
& \vec{u},\vec{v} \in R^n
\end{align}

Note that '$\geq_c$' is componentwise inequality.

I know if both $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are positive vectors, then the optimum solution is $\lambda^* = \underset{1 \leq i \leq n}{\max}\, \left(\frac{\vec{v}_i}{\vec{u}_i}\right)$, which would make all elements in $\lambda \vec{u}$ to be above or equals to the corresponding element in $\vec{v}$.

I want to know if there exists any mathematical solution for this problem, when $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ contains both positive and negative elements. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: your notation is confusing. Are you summing something? What are you summing? You have no index of summation. And what do you mean by $\geq_c$?

Comment: @MrYouMath:  '$\geq_c$' is componentwise inequality. Basically, I want to maximize the number of elements in $\lambda \vec{u}$ which are above $\vec{v}$. So, I'm counting the number of elements in $\lambda \vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ which satisfies the inequality.